# Database file cannot be found

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 project I'm using (with the help of LINQ-2-SQL) a local database (SQLite probably) created by another member of the team.

But when I run the application, it throws an exception:

```
The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX}\Local\database.sdf ]
```

The `.sdf` file with the database is in the project in `/Database/database.sdf` and the properties are set to `Build action: Embedded resource & Copy to output directory: Copy always`.

In the `databaseContext.cs`, which is a class used as context (not sure I'm naming it right, I'm new to linq-2-sql), the connection string is defined as:

```
Data Source=isostore:/database.sdf
```

**Is this the right settings? What can I do to make it work?**

Comment: I haven't played with this, but maybe you need to Copy file from ResourceStream to IsolatedStorage first. Similar like `CopyToIsolatedStorage()` at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_HowtoPlayBackgroundAudio). It is just a guess but maybe will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to move the database to isolated storage first. Heres how you could do it.

```
public static void MoveReferenceDatabase()
    {
        // Obtain the virtual store for the application.
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // Create a stream for the file in the installation folder.
        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("DutchMe.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            // Create a stream for the new file in the local folder.
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("DutchMe.sdf"))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the file from the installation folder to the local folder. 
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Else
set the connection string to Data Source=appdata:/database.sdf . I am not very sure about the second solution.